# if statement to call bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

i have a bit of js code i am trying to get it so when cat2 occurs it activates a modal

so i have tried     if (cat2) { $('#myModal').modal('show') };  but that isnt working for me

i have had a look around but havent found a answer yet

this is where i found the code http://www.hungrypiranha.org/make-a-website/html-quiz

```
                        $(document).ready(function() 
                        {    $("#results").click(function() {                

                        if (!$("input[@name=q1]:checked").val()          
                        ) {            
                        alert("You're not done yet!");        
                        }        

                        else {            
                        var cat1name = "1";            
                        var cat2name = "none";                                            


                        var cat1 = ($("input[@name=q1]:checked").val() != "a");   

                        var cat2 = (!cat1); var categories = [];                        

                        if (cat1) { categories.push(cat1name) };            
                        if (cat2) { categories.push(cat2name) };                                                      

                        var catStr = 'You answered the following questions incorrectly: ' + categories.join(', ') + '';                     
                        $("#categorylist").text(catStr);                        
                        $("#categorylist").show("slow");            

                        if (cat1) { $("#category1").show("slow"); };            
                        if (cat2) { $("#category2").show("slow"); };                                   
                        { $("#closing").show("slow"); };
                        }
                            });});
```

Comment: The `{ $("#closing").show("slow"); };` line doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

If yor want to extend modal functionalty of boostrap in JS, the best solution is to use plugin like this

http://bootboxjs.com/

And tha you can just envoke it like this

```
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "I am a custom dialog",
  title: "Custom title",
  buttons: {
    success: {
      label: "Success!",
      className: "btn-success",
      callback: function() {
        alet"great success");
      }
    },
    danger: {
      label: "Danger!",
      className: "btn-danger",
      callback: function() {
        alert("uh oh, look out!");
      }
    },
    main: {
      label: "Click ME!",
      className: "btn-primary",
      callback: function() {
        alert("Primary button");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i dont think that will do what im after, i dont need to do anything within the modal i would just like to call it, after they have clicked the correct answer.
This is the type of question style i will be asking them 
http://www.hungrypiranha.org/make-a-website/html-quiz